# How do I setup webhooks for transfer

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am a bit new to stripe. I am using it in node.js. Earlier today I had created stripe.transfers.create({}) object. Now in the webhook, I want to set the logic for when the transfer is complete or it fails. So I tried setting up the transfer.paid and transfer.failed webhook. But I did not receive any event.

My webhook code looks somewhat like this:

```
else if (webhookEvents.type === "transfer.paid") {
     // Update transfer to Success in DB
    } else if (webhookEvents.type === "transfer.failed") {
      // Update transfer back to Pending in DB
    }
```

The transfer begins when the stripe.transfers.create({}) is hit on button click and DB updates transfer to processing. But the transfer.paid block is never hit. I have a transfer.created block aswell and it runs everytime I start a transfer. Can anyone please help me in setting up the webhook events for a failed or successful transfer of a connected account. I need to setup the success and fail case for a transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, "transfers" were used the way Payouts are used today. You can read Stripe's documentation on the split [here](https://stripe.com/docs/transfer-payout-split). The events you're
looking at are related to the old "payout" transfers, and no longer apply to transfers of funds between Stripe accounts. To listen for Connect-related transfers (which will succeed or fail synchronously with your request), you can subscribe to `transfer.created` events ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-transfer.created)).